# Could somebody explain me how consume web services(REST JSON) made in php from java desktop?

Tags: java, php, rest, web-services, desktop

I got this example code but the response is an "Exception in NetClientGet:- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect"

I'm using jdk 1.8.

This is my example code:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/ServiciosWebLT/peoples");//your url i.e fetch data from .
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your Java application is running in an environment that does not allow making network connections. Can you tell us more about how you're running the Java app?

Comment: Are you *sure* your REST web-app is running on your machine, that it is listening to port 80, and that it services `/ServiciosWebLT/peoples` for *anonymous* connections? --- If entering `http://localhost/ServiciosWebLT/peoples` in a web browser works, then you might already be logged in (saved in a cookie), or you may be logging in automatically with your windows user, but `HttpURLConnection` doesn't support automatic windows user login.

Comment: the java app in running in local @Joni

Comment: the java app is running in locally and the web-service too
----------------------
Yes the REST service accept anonymous connections,
Yes, In a web browser works

Comment: Do you use a VPN or a firewall of some kind? Which operating system, Windows?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 firewall @Joni

Comment: Can you turn the firewall off for a minute? It might be blocking connections

Comment: It worked, the antivirus' firewall was blocking connections, Thanks @Joni